# Find out current age of cookie using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, cookies

Is there a way to find out the current age of a cookie?

For example, I want an overlay to appear on each visit for the first 30 days of the cookie, and then to no longer display after 30 days.

I'm setting a cookie with a far off expiration date using a jquery cookie plugin:

```
$.cookie("MyCookie", "true", {
  path: "/",
  expires: 9999
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to understand the age of the cookie, why not create another one? In addition to yours with `expires: 9999`:

```
$.cookie('monthCookie', true, { expires: 30 });

//later in code
if ($.cookie('monthCookie')) {
//show some content
}
else {
//do other stuff
}
```

Comment: I'll probably use a version of this if checking for a cookie's age is not an option. Thanks!